# JQuery tr add class after first 5 rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have n-tables on a page.  I need to go through every table on the page and within each table i need to add a class to the rows but NOT the first 5 rows.

My current js:

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
   var trCount = $("tbody > tr", this).size();
   alert(trCount);
});
```

This goes through and tells me how many tr's I have in each row.  However I need to then go through each row and if the current row is more than the 5th row then add classes to it..

So hopefully I get the following:

```
<table class='selector'>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class='hidden'><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class='hidden'><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class='hidden'><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class='hidden'><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class='hidden'><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("table").each(function() {
  $("tr:gt(4)", this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

**Note:** the `:gt(n)` pseudo-class is zero-based so the first five rows are o to 4.