# jQuery display 5 records on multiple tables

Tags: jquery

I have multiple tables using tablesorter on a page but only need to show the top 5 results on each.

I have tried to expand on this but it is only keeping first in the first table. I need this done on each table.

`$('.tablesorter > tbody').children('tr:not(:first)').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tablesorter > tbody')each(function(){
   $(this).children('tr:lt(5)').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks every looking and looking I did finally find this reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874554/jquery-tr-add-class-after-first-5-rows